# Table View Passing value that is in database to UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am trying to get the value that is stored in my database over a table view and I was successful, now my table view has *URL* values over it, what I want is when I click a specific cell the value on that cell goes to my `UIWebView` and it loads.

For this I have made a navigation controller and I am pushing it whenever any row is selected.

I am pasting my code in here for your help .

For TABLE VIEW :

```
**- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [appdelegate.tablearr count];


}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Simple"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Simple"]autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary*) [appdelegate.tablearr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    scanValue = (NSString*) [rowVals objectForKey:@"descrip"];
    cell.textLabel.text = scanValue;

     // Set up the cell
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *DVC = [[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 //   DVC.characterNumber = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"%@ PASSING VALUE",scanValue);
    DVC.detailstr = scanValue;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];
}**
```

In my `DETAIL VIEW CONTROLLER` , I have made a `NSString *detailstr` that stores in whatever is coming from scanValue.

```
**- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


   SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    NSLog(@"WHAT IS COMING HERE %@",detailstr);

    NSString *urladdress = detailstr;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urladdress];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];**
```

Now can anyone help me in the code stuff, any help would we really helpful to me.

Comment: could you please explain what problems r u facing...u didn't explain ur problem.

Comment: How can i pass the value from the table cell to the UIWeb View so that the table cell i click the value in that table cell should pass in the UIWeb View ?

Comment: According to ur old code, always the same value was sending to next view, but now it would be as per the select cell. please use the latest code i send u\

Answer (score 0):

I have added some more lines in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method so please replace old one with new one.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DetailViewController *DVC = [[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary*) [appdelegate.tablearr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

scanValue = (NSString*) [rowVals objectForKey:@"descrip"];
NSLog(@"%@ PASSING VALUE",scanValue);
DVC.detailstr = scanValue;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:DVC animated:YES];}
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE DUDE MAN ... THANK YOU SO MUCH ...
I WILL NEED A LOT OH HELP .. KEEP HELPING PEOPLE LIKE ME 

THANK YOU WITH ALL MY HEART

Comment: thanks,
If you are satisfy with my solution/suggestion then mark as accept my answer.. or upvoat the answer